# Bootstrap dropdown menu with dropdownList having a issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu which works fine , when i focus out the menu closes automatically as expected .

I have a requirement to add a Drop-down to the menu so i can do my selections respectively but strange thing happening is when i try selecting something in dropdown the menu closes automatically.

**Html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><ul class="dropdown"><li><select><option>cool</option><option>cooler</option><option>coolest</option></select></li></ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

sample **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27836/)** which shows the issue

**PS:** Actually its a IE issue in my local its works fine in chrome tough in fiddle it doesn't work anywhere.

I don't want menu to loose focus when i am selecting something which is inside the menu .

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown-menu also closes when you click inside it. You should add (or maybe remove?) some JS (or jQuery if you prefer that) that avoids the dropdown menu from closing when you click INSIDE it.

Comment: Hmm, if you press and hold the dropdown menu in the page 1 dropdown, you can select options fine, I'll look more into this....

Comment: @Rvervuurt we can use `stopPropagation` but it will work in chrome in fiddle/my-local but its again a un-resolved case in IE 11 too .